# Can I send transactions async using polkadot-js

Tags: javascript, substrate, polkadot, polkadot-js

I have walked through the official document and found a page about how to transfer using polkadot-js https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/examples/promise/make-transfer

```js
const transfer = api.tx.balances.transfer(BOB, 12345);
const hash = await transfer.signAndSend(alice);
```

I want to know if I can split the `signAndSend` method into two and execute at different machines. like in a client machine, in the browser compute the signature.

```js
const transfer = api.tx.balances.transfer(BOB, 12345);
const signature = await transfer.signAsync(alice);
```

and then in the server side send the transfer transaction.

```js
const mockSigner = createMockSigner(signature); // signature is computed from the client side and send to server over HTTP
const transfer = api.tx.balances.transfer(BOB, 12345);
const res = transfer.send({signer: mockSigner});
```

The above example doesn't work, I just want to express if I can do sign and send in different machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signing a transaction on one computer and sending it from a second computer is definitely possible.

[PolkadotJS Tools](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-transaction-construction#polkadot-js-tools) contains a method for building and signing a transaction offline. You can find the source [here](https://github.com/polkadot-js/tools/blob/master/packages/signer-cli/src/cmdSendOffline.ts). Please note that building the transaction in the browser will still require access to a polkadot node (the `endpoint` in the code).

> The signer sendOffline command has the exact same API, but will not
> broadcast the transaction. submit and sendOffline must be connected to
> a node to fetch the current metadata and construct a valid
> transaction. Their API has the format:

Therefore, you'd need to run a [light client](https://github.com/polkadot-js/client) in the browser in order to have access to current block information or attach to some other node endpoint outwith the browser.

Comment: Thanks, I read something about sign offline, still don't quite understand why sign offline is so difficult and different in substrate. Is that means that in online mode, when calling `api.tx.balance.transfer` a transfer object is unique so its signature can't be send to other machine? And in offline mode we construct transfer object manually so  the signature can be shared?

Comment: Fundamentally both sign offline and online are doing the same thing in terms of signing. [cmdSendOffline.ts](https://github.com/polkadot-js/tools/blob/master/packages/signer-cli/src/cmdSendOffline.ts) creates the transaction payload and signs it then dumps it to JSON. [cmdSign.ts](https://github.com/polkadot-js/tools/blob/master/packages/signer-cli/src/cmdSign.ts) signs a payload only. You can also pass the `submit` command on the CLI in which case the signed payload from [cmdSign](https://github.com/polkadot-js/tools/blob/master/packages/signer-cli/src/cmdSubmit.ts) is submitted

Answer (score 0):

The offline sign version:
https://gist.github.com/xcaptain/4d190232411dcf27441d9fadd7ff6988

The online sign version:

```js
const transfer = api.tx.balances.transfer(BOB, 12345);
const signedExtrinsic = await transfer.signAsync(alice).toJSON();
await api.rpc.author.submitExtrinsic(signedExtrinsic);
```

Don't know what's the difference, but they both work.